# Create folder inside folder OneDrive in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, onedrive

OneDrive has the option to create a folder from iOS application. I have created it with the help of the following method:

```
[self.liveClient postWithPath:@"me/skydrive" dictBody:newFolder delegate:self userState:@"create folder"];
newFolder = NSDictionary with folder details including folder name.
```

Folder name I created here is `xyz`.

Now when I tried to create a sub folder inside this particular folder with the following path:

```
[self.liveClient postWithPath:@"me/skydrive/xyz" dictBody:newFolder delegate:self userState:@"create folder"];
```

Here `xyz` is the now the existing folder inside one drive.

But now it throws me the error below:

> LiveServicesErrorDomain error 5.

Comment: Have you checked out [the new OneDrive API](https://dev.onedrive.com/) and the associated [iOS SDK](https://github.com/onedrive/onedrive-sdk-ios)? I'd suggesting going down that route instead of using the older API.

Comment: Finally Success! After creating xyz folder when you fetch files "me/skydrive/files" it returns dictionary which contain your specific folder information with folder id on skydive, just use that folder id as a path to create new folder inside it.

Comment: Thanks for updating us Sandeep! Can you write, and accept, your answer for this question so that others can see you figured it out without reading the comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution.

Step1:

First create the folder on the root of the one drive through following method:

```
[self.liveClient postWithPath:@"me/skydrive" dictBody:newFolder delegate:self userState:@"create folder"];
```

newFolder = NSDictionary with folder details including folder name.
Name the subfolder name anything let say abc

This will create xyz folder on the root of the one drive cloud.

Step2:

Fetch the path of the xyz folder created on the one drive cloud. To do so use the following query:

```
[self.liveClient getWithPath:@"me/skydrive/files" delegate:self userState:@"me/skydrive/files"];
```

In response you will receive data in the form of JSON format which actually a array of dictionaries. For dictionary specific to xyz folder there will be a key name as "id" whose value will be the path to reach inside xyz folder.

Step3:

Now, to create a subfolder run the following query:

```
[self.liveClient postWithPath:id dictBody:newFolder delegate:self userState:@"create subfolder"];
```

newFolder = NSDictionary with folder details including folder name.

id = id is the path of the folder xyz fetched in the step2.

This will create abc subfolder inside xyz folder on the one drive cloud.